# Regex to find text after last occurence of character till another one

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to find a regular expression to extract information starting with " including: " and ending with the text after the last occurence of the character "\n*" or "\n•" until the character "\n". In other words, i am trying to find an ending as the first occurence of "\n" right after the last occurence of "\n*" or "\n•". I have tried this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6v0m5m/1) but doesn't work as i want it to. I would like to include the next sentence untill "guidance.\n".
I am using python and i am trying to extract that to a new column in my pandas DataFrame called "Skills". The "Job Description" column has the information

```
df["Skills"]=df["Job description"].str.extract("including:((?:.)*\\n[*|•])")
```

Comment: Perhaps like this `including:(.*?\\n[*•]).*?\\n(?![*•])` https://regex101.com/r/MXJwD2/1 or if the newline is a real newline `\bincluding:(.*?\n[*•]).*?\n(?![*•])` https://regex101.com/r/S0ROfE/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think that's not correct. See this one https://regex101.com/r/IwHMCN/1 . It doesn't find the last occurence of "\n*" .

Comment: @Prestyy like this? https://regex101.com/r/duPzQm/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
(?s)\bincluding:(.*\\n[*•]).*?\\n(?![*•])
```

- `(?s)` Inline modifier to make the dot match a newline
- `\bincluding:` Match `including:` preceded by a word boundary
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.*\\n[*•]` Match till the last occurrence of `\n` followed by either * or •
- `(` Close group 1
- `.*?\\n` Match till the first occurrence of `\n`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mEmPJr/1)

Or when `\\n` is a real newline

```
(?s)\bincluding:(.*\n[*•]).*?\n(?![*•])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4SOQQr/1)

For example

```
df["Skills"] = df["Job description"].str.extract(r"(?s)\bincluding:(.*\n[*•]).*?\n(?![*•])")
```

Comment: @Prestyy I have added the code that I use to get the value of capture group 1 in the column "Skills"

Comment: Yes man! I just made a slight change of the returned group to get the text until the '\n' (including that)  like this r"(?s)\bincluding:(.*\n[*•].*?\n)(?![*•])"  , as i noted before. You can edit it if you want so. Thanks for giving me the answer.